# section indexed with 12 hour clock format

Tags: iphone

There is a way to create a section index based on alphabets which is pretty easy and straightforward using UILocalizedIndexedCollation. 
Is there a way to create a section index based on 12 hour clock? Like using "HH:mm a" and using that as the section header.

Sagos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: in your data source to return the headers.

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12:00 AM", @"01:00 AM", ..., @"11:00 PM", nil];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 24;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch(section) {
        case 0: //12:00 AM
            ...
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0: //12:00 AM
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am parsing the file and storing in DB and then creating tableview, I may not use static number for numberOfSections. But other than that thanks a lot for anwering to my query.